# Declaring a Variable TableAdapter on a Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tableadapter

This is hopefully a fairly straightforward question.

I am building a generic search form in my application.  This will allow the user to search for various records throughout the application.

The one thing I cannot seem to figure out is how to allow the declaration of the TableAdapter to change at run-time.  Each part of the app will be passing a variable to the search form to specify which table should be loaded.

In the form class I have the following:

```
FRIEND WITHEVENTS tbaSearchData AS database.databaseTableAdapters.TableOneTableAdapter
```

This is great for TableOne.  But, I have about a hundred tables that could be searched through.

To load the data I'm using a DataGridView and populating it via a private method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableadapter is really meant for design time setup and doesn't easily change at runtime. You may want to look into using a DataAdapter, like SqlDataAdapter, for these requests. These objects have lower overhead and aren't as type specific as a tableadapter so making them at runtime is a decent solution.

Comment: It took a bit, but the SQL Adapter is doing exactly what I needed.  You mentioned it also having lower overhead.  Is using the SQLAdapter generally a better alternative then using the TableAdapters when the SQL database has been added a datasource?

Comment: I think it depends on what you are doing. When you know most of your data structure ahead of time you can use the tableadapter and a typed dataset that it generates and writing the code is easier. However for runtime flexibility I don't use tableadapters and typed datasets. I create my stuff on the fly. Sometimes it is harder to reference objects but its a equal tradeoff because I can make my sqladapter behave exactly as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood this.
I've come up with two possible solutions

1. From various point of your app, you could pass the specialized DataAdapter itself instead of a tablename and assign to a generic DataAdapter variable into the search form.
2. You could create a generic DataAdapter into the search form and change the SQL command used to load the data. In the following code, `da` will be a DataAdapter and `table` the tablename passed to the search form

`da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from " & table`